# Undefined in Split String

Tags: javascript

i have a function to split string into 2 part, front and back. Then reverse it to back and front. Here is my code

```
function reverseString(string) {
    let splitString = ""
    let firstString = ""

    for(i = 0; i <= string.length/2 - 1; i++) {
        firstString += string[i]
    }

    for(i = string.length/2; i <= string.length; i++) {
        splitString += string[i]
    }
    return splitString + firstString
}
```

Sorry for bad explanation, this is test case and expected result (first one is expected result, the second one is my result)

```
console.log(reverseString("aaabccc")); // "cccbaaa" "undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedaaa"
console.log(reverseString("aab")); // "baa" "undefinedundefineda"
console.log(reverseString("aaaacccc")); // "ccccaaaa" "ccccundefinedaaa"
console.log(reverseString("abcdefghabcdef")); // "habcdefabcdefg" "habcdefundefinedabcdefg"
```

could you help me, whats wrong with it. Thank you

Comment: When `string.length` is odd, `string.length/2` is not an integer.

Comment: Another problem is `i <= string.length`. It should be `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: Said another way, what should `string[1.5]` return?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it should return the original string, for example if "aaabccc" "cccbaaa"

Comment: It's not related to your `undefined`, but you also need to declare `i`. Righ tnow your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and creating a **global** `i` variable.

Comment: So, the code point at the one and a half-th index of the string should be the entire string? That's a weird way of constructing strings, not to mention arrays. It also goes against how the language is defined.

Comment: `const reverseString = s => { const midLower = Math.floor(s.length / 2), midHigher = Math.ceil(s.length / 2); return s.slice(midHigher) + s.slice(midLower, midHigher) + s.slice(0, midLower); };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try another approach and use the `slice` function

```js
function reverseString(string) 
{
    if (string.length < 2) { return string; }

    let stringHalfLength = string.length / 2;
    let isLengthOdd = stringHalfLength % 1 !== 0;
    
    if (isLengthOdd) {
        return string.slice(Math.ceil(stringHalfLength), string.length + 1) + string[Math.floor(stringHalfLength)] + string.slice(0, Math.floor(stringHalfLength));
    }
    
    return string.slice(stringHalfLength, string.length + 1) + string.slice(0, stringHalfLength);
}

console.log(reverseString("aaabccc") === "cccbaaa"); 
console.log(reverseString("aab") === "baa"); 
console.log(reverseString("aaaacccc") === "ccccaaaa"); 
console.log(reverseString("abcdefghabcdef") === "habcdefabcdefg");
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to reverse the string would be to split the string, then use the built-in `reverse` javascript function (which reverses the elements of the split string), and then re-join the elements using the `join` function.. No need to re-invent the wheel?

You can concatenate the functions in shorthand (.split.reverse.join etc...) so your function would look something like this:

```
function reverseString(string) {
    return string.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Try it out!

```js
function reverseString(string) {
  return string.split("").reverse().join("");
}

console.log(reverseString("hello"));
console.log(reverseString("aaabbbccc"));
```

If there's a particular reason you're opting not to use the in-built functions (i.e. if I've missed something?) , feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

The short version of what you need:

```
function reverseString(string) {
    const splitPosition = Math.ceil(string.length / 2);
    return string.substring(splitPosition) + string.substring(0, splitPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to your question is the middle element. To accomplish that, you probably want to use `Math.floor` that round under.

`console.log(reverseString("aaabccc")); // "cccbaaa"`
`console.log(reverseString("abcdefghabcdef")); // "habcdefabcdefg"`

```
function reverseString (str) {
    if (str.length<2) {
        return str
    }
    var half = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
    return (str.slice(-half) + (str.length%2?str[half]:"")  + str.slice(0,half));
}

reverseString('')
> ""

reverseString('1')
> "1"

reverseString('12')
> "21"

reverseString('123')
> "321"

reverseString('1234')
> "3412"

reverseString('12345')
> "45312"

reverseString("aaabccc")
> "cccbaaa"

reverseString("abcdefghabcdef")
> "habcdefabcdefg"
```

So basically your problem is not to grab 2 parts of the string and rearrange, it is to grab 3 parts.

- 1 part: `str.slice(0,half)`
- 2 part: `str.length%2 ? str[half] : ""`
- 3 part: `str.slice(-half)`

The second part is empty if the string length is even and the middle character if is odd.

So the code version in long self explanatory code:

```
function reverseString (str) {
    if (str.length<2) {
        return str
    }

    var half = Math.floor(str.length / 2);

    var firstPart = str.slice(0,half);
    var midlePart = str.length % 2 ? str[half] : ""; // we could expand also this
    var endPart = str.slice(-half);

    return endPart + midlePart + firstPart;
 }
```

And also, notice the precondition, so I don't have to deal with the easy cases.

Also, in your code, you got undefined because you access in the last loop to:
`string[string.length]` you need to change `<=` by `<`